# Floating Action Button android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Could someone help me? the moment I press on the FloatingActionButton the activity is closed and goes back. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class Regolamento extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regolamento);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "English", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                tv.setText("ciao");

            }
        });
    }}
```

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".Regolamento"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_regolamento">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="wow"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How should i do? Can someone help me? until just before everything worked then suddenly it stopped working

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
>      method 'void 
>      android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a 
>       null object reference
>       at     com.example.bbmarinablu.Regolamento$1.onClick(Regolamento.java:29)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(Unknown Source:17)
>       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(Unknown Source:3)
>       at android.view.View.access$3500(Unknown Source:0)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(Unknown Source:8)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:242)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:98)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:275)

Comment: Post the full xml code and imported classes

Comment: there is nothing in `onClick` that could lead to an error, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: By going back do you mean it crashes, in which case you should be able to view the error in Logcat to see what happens. 

From what you have posted here since I dont see ```android:id="@+id/text"``` in your xml I'm assuming you get a null pointer exception causing a crash. Posting some helpful code would help us locate the issue if this isn't the cause

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting. You can find it in the `Run` tab in Android Studio.

Comment: I added the error I get from the app above when I start it

Comment: any update for this ?

Comment: no, I was unable to fix

Comment: please update your post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define id `text` in `activity_regolamento.xml`.

Add `android:id="@+id/text"` in `TextView` element.